# Copying source files into a Visual Studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've created a new Visual Studio C++ project and I'd like to import copies of a number of C and header files into the project. That is, the files are currently in a folder on my desktop and I'd like to import them such that copies are placed in the newly created project folder.

How would I do this? I've tried using **File | New | Project from Existing Code** but that just keeps the files in their existing location. I've even tried a simple **Ctrl-C** and **Ctrl-V** and again that imported the files but they stayed in the same place on disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the files to the new location in Windows Explorer, then start Visual Studio and add them as existing items to the project.

Comment: I will just add that you also have to do "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer to be able to see and add them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution would be to create a new (empty) project and add your h and cpp files per "Add -> Existing item" in the context menu of "Headers" and "Sources"

Comment: That keeps the files at their original location (i.e. in the old project). I assume the project is to continue separately, so the op needs copies of the files instead linking the original ones.

Comment: Same problem; the files stay in their existing location.